# Googlebot couldn't get all resources for this page

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot

hi I'm getting this error googlebot couldn't get all resources for this page Here's a List. I put my website into Google Search Console and there are setup errors that show up when the Googlebot tries to parse the page. It appears like I can just disable the shortcodes, but I would prefer to avoid that. I have other plugins where I was able to include all the .js includes in the body of the page. is that possible in this situation?
i getting this error in .js file and from some plugins, shortcode

[image: Image Here]

Comment: When it says "blocked ... robots.txt", could you be blocking these in your robots.txt?

Comment: @Rup yes I blocked. Point me in the right direction How should I do to overcome this issue.

Comment: @Rup sorry I didn't block robots.txt. I get this error by Googlebot

Comment: @Husna The contents of robots.txt are telling Googlebot not to index the first entry in your list. So that file has to be edited if you want that script to get indexed.